# Awk function with optional argument

Tags: awk

Is this a good way to allow an optional user argument `ngt` to an awk function ?

```
function nbstring(str, ngt) {
  ## Test whether string STR is non-blank.
  ## Return true when STR is non-blank.
  if (length(gensub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", "g", str)) > 0) {
   if ( ngt == "dump" ) { print "return 1 for " str }
   return 1
  } else {
   if ( ngt == "dump" ) { print "return 0 for " str }
   return 0
  }
 }
```

I have also used the condition

```
if (str && length(gensub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", "g", str)) > 0) {
```

and I get the same result.

Thusly, I do not think that doing `str &&` is needed, right?

Comment: Try that last piece of code with `str` being a non-empty non-blank string such as `0`.

Comment: When I pass `nv = 0`, I get return `0`. But then `nv` is not a string.  Your test is too cryptic, and do not understand its intention.

Comment: I still think that I should not use the additional condition `str &&`.

Comment: What was your intent in adding `str &&`?

Comment: My comment at the top was just intended to show that if you use a variable's value as a boolean test, the value `0` is _false_, which means that its not an adequate test for "string is not empty".

Comment: Yes, the value `0` is false.

Comment: Yes it is and so is the value of the null string `""` but what were you trying to accomplish with `str &&`? You clearly had something in mind by doing that but it's not clear what that "something" was and it's unlikely that whatever you had in mind adding `str &&` was the right way to do it. If you can tell us what you were trying to do, we can help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just trying to test if a string contains any non-blanks? That'd be this in any POSIX awk (no need for the non-POSIX `gensub()`, nor any other `*sub()` function, nor a call to `length()`):

```
function nbstring(str, ngt,    rslt) {
  ## Test whether string STR is non-blank.
  ## Return true when STR is non-blank.
  rslt = ( str ~ /[^[:blank:]]/ ) 
  if ( ngt == "dump" ) {
    printf "return %d for %s\n", rslt, str
  }
  return rslt
}
```

Comment: Or to *count* the non-blanks, `n = gsub (/[^[:blank:]]/, "&", str);`

Comment: No, want to test if it is only blanks with no useful information.

Comment: Are you commenting on my answer or responding to @Paul_Pedant's comment?

Comment: My bad. @EdMorton 's answer stops parsing at the first non-blank, and returns a true (1) value for it. My comment counts all non-blanks (so parses the whole string), and returns that count (e.g.4) which is also truthy. So equivalent test, but slower and more obscure.

Comment: @EdMorton How can I change  `str ~ /[^[:blank:]]/`  to test if `str` is all blanks ?

Comment: @Enver `str ~ /^[[:blank:]]+$/`. Change `+` to `*` if you want to consider an empty `str` as being the same as "all blanks". You COULD alternatively write `str !~ /[^[:blank:]]/` but then you have a double negative, "str does NOT contain a char that is NOT a blank", which is always harder to understand than positive logic so I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: You are right, it is harder doing all the negations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for idiomatic `awk` code I could offer this, but it's not really much different to your own suggestion,

```
function nbstring(str, ngt,  x) {
    x = (length(gensub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", "g", str)) > 0);
    if (ngt == "dump") { printf "return %d for < %s >\n", x, str };
    return x;
}
```

You can call `nbstring(str, ngt)` or `nbstring(str)`, or indeed `nbstring()`, as there is no counting of arguments to a function.